# Long variable names in MS BASIC

Tags: microsoft-basic

From [the Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BASIC):

> The final major release of BASIC-80 was version 5.x, which appeared in
>   1981 and added support for 40-character variable names, WHILE...WEND
>   loops, dynamic string allocation, and several other features. BASIC
>   5.x removed the ability to crunch program lines.

I'm only familiar with the 6502 code for MS BASIC, which had the two-char name limit.

Does anyone know how they implemented long names? Did they simply expand the variable table? Did they separate the names to their own list? Use the 2 bytes to point to the string in the source?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure if that helps, but original BASICA and GWBASIC are ports of BASIC-80 V5.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They expanded the variable table. Each entry starts with a type byte
followed immediately by the full variable name.

This is based on an analysis of the Microsoft BASIC-80 5.2 source code
[found here](https://winworldpc.com/download/c2bfc380-c2b2-c2b4-7d00-11c3a7c29d25). The core of the interpreter is `BINTRP.MAC`,
which has most of the definitions used here. This includes `NAMCNT`
(one byte) and `NAMBUF` (`NAMLEN - 2` bytes), which are pre-allocated
storage for a copy of a variable name read from the program text, and
`VARTAB`, a pointer to the start of the area (immediately after the
program text, I believe) that stores the current list of variable
names and values when running.

The routine I looked at was `PTRGET` in `BIPTRG.MAC`, which reads a
variable name at the current text position pointed to by `HL` and
stores a pointer to its value in the location pointed to by `DE`.

The core of the variable name search is `LOPTOP`, which is entered with
`BC` containing the first two chars of the variable name, `DE` pointing
into `VARTAB` and storage `NAMCNT` and `NAMBUF` containing the name length
count and chars beyond the first two.

`LOPTOP` compares the first char of the variable name (in `C`) with
the first char of the name in `VARTAB`, then compares the variable
type, then the second char of the name (in `D`). I'm guessing that
this was the original full comparision routine in earlier versions of
BASIC. If all of these match, it continues on with `FINPTR`, which
compares the remaining name chars in `NAMBUF` with the rest of the
name in `VARTAB`.

*Postscript:* I've found [a disassembly of Altair Basic 3.2](http://altairbasic.org/).
The symbol names are different for obvious reasons, but its routine
[`GetVar`] is clearly the `PTRGET` routine above. The start of it is
almost identical, the main differences being that "read next char" is
a routine called with `RST` rather than a `MOV C,M` and that the first
and second characters are in `B` and `C` rather than vice versa. There
are larger differences in the specific code for `LOPTOP` (called
`FindVarLoop` in the disassembly), some related to the [simplified
variable storage](http://altairbasic.org/int_ex.htm) (here called `VAR_BASE`), but the
overall structure is clearly the same. The [memory arrangement
overview](http://altairbasic.org/int_ex.htm) is helpful reading before diving into either
this or the 5.2 source code.

Comment: Most excellent, I had not found that source online. Are VARTAB and NAMBUF two tables, or is NAMBUF a pointer within VARTAB?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz They're completely separate; `NAMEBUF` is pre-allocated temporary storage for a variable name and `VARTAB` is the pointer to the variable table. I've updated the question to describe these better.